# Undefined property: stdClass::$test

Tags: php, laravel-4.2

I get this error from this line

```
<p><strong>{{ Lang::choice('messages.test-type',1) }}</strong>
    {{$unhlsspecimen->test->testType->name}}</p> <!-- query failing unhls -->
</p>
```

`dd(var_dump($unhlsspecimen))` gives me the following:

> object(stdClass)#839 (25) { ["id"]=> int(30) ["visit_id"]=> int(18) ["test_type_id"]=> int(1) ["specimen_id"]=> int(30) ["interpretation"]=> string(0) "" ["test_status_id"]=> int(2) ["created_by"]=> int(1) ["tested_by"]=> int(0) ["verified_by"]=> int(0) ["requested_by"]=> string(19) "kBLIS Administrator" ["time_created"]=> string(19) "2016-10-05 10:24:21" ["time_started"]=> NULL ["time_completed"]=> NULL ["time_verified"]=> NULL ["time_sent"]=> NULL ["external_id"]=> NULL ["specimen_type_id"]=> int(23) ["specimen_status_id"]=> int(2) ["accepted_by"]=> int(1) ["rejected_by"]=> int(0) ["rejection_reason_id"]=> NULL ["reject_explained_to"]=> NULL ["referral_id"]=> NULL ["time_accepted"]=> string(19) "2016-10-12 13:16:49" ["time_rejected"]=> NULL } NULL

Comment: Some thing isn't right. Your error message and var_dump don't match. You also seem to have multiple dumps. Is this in a loop?

Comment: Sorry  had placed this bit of code in my routes to see raw sql queries  Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query)
    {
        var_dump($query); Have updated var_dump

Comment: So what's your question? The var_dump clearly shows you don't have a property `test` in your object, just as PHP is warning you about.

Comment: Oh ok I see,  let me look at my joins and models to see why this is so working parrallel to existing code base ....thanks, I suppose my object should be different given I have renamed lots of things.....thanks